# Why is my conditional printing its condition value?

Tags: reactjs

I have a conditional to show top nav only when logged in:

```
  const [adminState, setAdminState] = useState({
    loggedIn: 0,
  });
  return (
    <AdminState.Provider value={[adminState, setAdminState]}>
      {adminState.loggedIn && <TopNav />} <--- this line is printing 0 when logged out
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </AdminState.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When logged out, it is printing the number "0" where the conditional is.

Comment: Simply try this one: `{adminState.loggedIn ? <TopNav /> : null}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: `&&` is the [logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) operator, not the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).*

Because `0 && <TopNav />` results in the value `0`, and React renders numbers when you provide them as children. It's just `null`, `undefined`, and booleans that it doesn't render ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored)).

Instead, either:

1. Use `false` instead of `0` for the `loggedIn` flag; then your `&&` expression will result in `false` and React won't display anything for that expression's result.

   Or
2. Use the actual conditional operator:

   ```js
   {adminState.loggedIn ? <TopNav /> : null}
   ```